# How to migrate RealmJS db after change the column type?

Tags: database, react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-js

I'm using `realmjs` DB in my react-native app where I have a schema `settings`. I want to change a property type of that schema from `int` to `string`. So I understand that I need to perform migration and I decided to perform a `linear` migration. For the migration I followed the example from Realm documentation and ended up doing something like below:

```
const schemaList = [schemaV1,schemaV2];
let nextSchemaIndex = Realm.schemaVersion(Realm.defaultPath);
while (nextSchemaIndex < schemaList.length) {
    const migratedRealm = new Realm(schemaList[nextSchemaIndex++]);
    migratedRealm.close();
}

export default new Realm(schemaList[schemaList.length - 1]);
```

`schemaV1` is the old version of the db and `schemaV2` is the latest version of the db after changes of property type. The `schemaV2` also has a migration function like below:

```
    if (oldRealm.schemaVersion < 1) {
        const oldObjects = oldRealm.objects(TBL_MOBILE_SETTING);
        const newObjects = newRealm.objects(TBL_MOBILE_SETTING);
        for (let i = 0; i < oldObjects.length; i++) {
            newObjects[i].module    = oldObjects[i].module;
            newObjects[i].setting   = oldObjects[i].setting;
        }
    }
```

But at the end, when I'm trying to run the app, it's crashing with an error message that

> *Database migration is needed*

Does it mean that the migration function in `schemaV2` never runs? If so, how to make sure that all the migration functions are running properly? Or am I missing something else?

**EDIT**

I found that column type change is not allowed in RealmJS and I added a new column and tried to perform migration but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was what I guessed. The migration function was not being called. I had to create an `export const` function and call the migration function in the `index` file cause it's the file which is called at the starting of the app.